# VPN Router and additional VPN on device

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I have a Router which I use as VPN server (openVPN is configured, unified mode).
In addition, I am connecting to the VPN of my company on the macbook which is connected to internet through the abovementioned router.

Router -------> Macbookpro ------> VPN (company)
(openVPN)

Is my public IP exposed to the company or only the IP of the openvpn configured in the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: It depends ... on what VPN client your company has and if you mean your internal private IP or what i expect, because of the configuration you described, you mean your own public IP

**your public IP:** Is your OpenVPN tunnel configured to tunnel everything (unified mode) or just some addresses (split mode)?
In **unified mode** your public IP won't be exposed to the company. In **split mode** your public IP won't be exposed if the traffic to the VPN Gateway is routed by your router into your VPN - you should have configured that.

**your internal private IP:** It depends on the software used to connect to the company. Some software allows access to diagnostic data so your IP might be visible.

EDIT: Regarding updated OP: no. Your Public IP wohnt be exposed to your company, as Long as the Tunnel to the others Site persists. You should block VPN ports/target for your client to avoid accidential connection when VPN in router is down.

Comment: router is configured in **unified mode** , and I meant **public IP** , I have updated the text in the question

Comment: Is my answer now OK for you? If yes, then select it as answer or ask another question